# Google reverse geocache API: Make lat & long from JSON a variable

Tags: json, node.js, object, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I am using the [NPM Geocoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geocoder) to convert locations to lat and longitude.  However I am not sure how to pull the lat and long from the output.

The JSON is below  and I want to make what's in line 59 and 60 a new variable.  How do I do this?

This isn't working:

```
   var location = data.results.geometry.location.lat;
```

_ JSON:

```
    {
  "results": [
    {
      "address_components": [
        {
          "long_name": "Kendall Park",
          "short_name": "Kendall Park",
          "types": [
            "neighborhood",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "South Brunswick Township",
          "short_name": "South Brunswick Township",
          "types": [
            "locality",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Middlesex County",
          "short_name": "Middlesex County",
          "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_2",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "New Jersey",
          "short_name": "NJ",
          "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_1",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "United States",
          "short_name": "US",
          "types": [
            "country",
            "political"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address": "Kendall Park, South Brunswick Township, NJ, USA",
      "geometry": {
        "bounds": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 40.4335151,
            "lng": -74.54167489999999
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 40.3944258,
            "lng": -74.586016
          }
        },
        "location": {
          "lat": 40.4209391,  //MAKE THIS A NEW VARIABLE
          "lng": -74.560711
        },
        "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 40.4335151,
            "lng": -74.54167489999999
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 40.3944258,
            "lng": -74.586016
          }
        }
      },
      "place_id": "ChIJqbniAsTCw4kRUI0mXQpaGAc",
      "types": [
        "neighborhood",
        "political"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

Comment: Is this the minimum required sample code to explain your challenge?

Answer (score 1):

data.results is an array, try this:

```
   var location = BuildLatLng(data.results[0].geometry.location.lat,
                              data.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
```

where `BuildLatLng()` is just whatever you need to use in your framework, the equivalent of `google.maps.LatLng` in the Google Maps JavaScript API.

And while you're at it, think about whether you really want to always take just the first result. Ideally, your apps should look at each `results[i].types` to decide which one to use.